# GoogleApiClient class not found

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I'm trying to use google fit api for getting step count.
I'm using the [starter guide](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/get-started)
When i try to paste the code

```
private GoogleApiClient mClient = null;
```

Android studio can't find the "com.google.android.gms.common.api" package and the  GoogleApiClient class.

i added

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
```

to my gradle.

Any suggestions? 
Thanks

EDIT:

I changed the gradle to 
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
And now it works... does any one know why the 7.0.0 doesn't work?
Thanks

Comment: Have you imported and added the `google-play-services` library project?

Comment: Yes I did, see my edit: i added compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0' to gradle not to manifest

Answer (score 1):

I have met similar bug before, I finally solved this problem using Android Studio.

You can using below steps to check in Andorid studio.

1) Open File->Project Structure
2) Check the Module's Dependencies.
[Check Dependencies.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7PRG.png)

3) I add Google play service library in common module. So I need to add dependencies to other modules.
[Link dependencies to other modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5On2P.png)

Hope this can help you.

Regards,

Richard